# How to move non-rotating objects together with the rotating ones on the same axis?

Tags: rigging, objects, bones

[image: here's my model in motion:]

I ultimately want to import into Unity a wheel that rotates, turns, and adjusts to the terrain. I'm wondering how to keep the frame and plate with the actual wheel that is spinning, while keeping everything but the wheel rigid. I also need to figure out how to animate the suspension/piston in relation to the hinges, but that is for a different question.

Thanks for any tips!

Here's the file if it helps: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id make it one whole object and then parent the wheel to the solid objects, everything needs to be parented. You can then use paint weights and constraints to get the different parts to animate correctly with bones/nodes.

Parenting should be some thing like a web tree. This is a over simplification but i think it works.

Hull has no parent, Doors and Mirrors is parented to the hull, Axel is parented to the hull, suspension is parented to the Axel and the wheels are parented to the suspension.